# Extract between two words in a string that has newlines

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like :

"Hey I am Peter I work as a Software Engineer. I know Java and I am new to RegEx".

I want to extract all characters from "Peter to new".

From gskinner.com/RegExr/  I can see that this pattern works - **(?<=Hey)([^\n]*)(?=Reg)**

But in Java, it does not work. Can any one please help ? What differently needs to be done in Java ?

My code looks like this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=Hey)([^\n]*)(?=Reg)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(p);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

When I run, I get an Exception which says "No match Found".

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
>       at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)

Comment: Can you try (?<=Hey)([^\\n]*)(?=Reg) instead, in case you need to escape the \ in the expression.

Comment: try to add multiline mode flag

Comment: Shouldn't that be `p.matcher(StringWithPeter)`?

Comment: I also don't really understand why that would work since `[^\n]` is a character class for any character *except* the newlines you are trying to match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a newline somewhere in your string to match, something like:

```
String stringWithPeter = "Hey I am Peter I work as a Software Engineer." +
    System.getProperty("line.separator") + "I know Java and I am new to RegEx";
```

And that you want to match across this newline.  You can tell Java to include newlines when matching dots ("."):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=Hey)(.*)(?=Reg)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Then you will get the behavior you're looking for.  I also found that when this worked:

```
String stringWithPeter = "Hey I am Peter I work as a Software Engineer.\nI know Java and I am new to RegEx";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=Hey)([^\r]*)(?=Reg)");
```

But I couldn't tell you why, exactly.

Comment: Thanks so much davidfmatheson

Comment: The `Pattern.DOTALL` was new to me, +1 for pointing to this live-saver.

Answer (score 1):

You have left an unescaped `\n` in your expression, which is being put into the string as a newline character.

Try:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=Hey)([^\\n]*)(?=Reg)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToMatch);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
```

instead.

[Credit also to user Explosion Pills for noticing the parameter to p.matcher was also incorrect]

Comment: Also, I don't think [^\\n] is what he really wants... Isn't that just equivalent to doing "."?! In which case, I'm confused why it ever appeared to "work"... If you want to match *anything* (including newlines), you can use [\\s\\S] (i.e. any whitespace or non-whitespace)

Comment: Yeah ExplosionPills, its my mistake . Thanks .

But still I tried running with Adrian's regexPattern. But still I am getting an Exception which says "No match Found" .

  public static void main(String... args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=Hey)([^\\n]*)(?=Reg)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Hey I am Peter \n I work as a Software Engineer. \n I know Java \n and I am new to RegEx");
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }

Comment: It makes no difference whether you escape the newline or not. Newlines are not special characters in regex. If you escape it, then regex turns it into a newline, if not regex treats the newline as a literal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one line:

```
String middle = str.replaceAll(".*(?<=Hey)([^\n]*)(?=Reg).*", "$1");
```

Here's a test:

```
String str = "Hey I am Peter I work as a Software Engineer. I know Java and I am new to RegEx";
String middle = str.replaceAll(".*(?<=Hey)([^\n]*)(?=Reg).*", "$1");
System.out.println(middle);
```

Output:

```
I am Peter I work as a Software Engineer. I know Java and I am new to
```

---

Note that you get the same results with this regex

```
String middle = str.replaceAll(".*(?<=Hey)(.*)(?=Reg).*", "$1");
```

Your regex is looking for a string of characters, all of which are *not* newlines.